# Why is my sprite image being cut off?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a handle for a progress bar on my website. I have the bar there and it works perfectly, but when I try to draw the handle above the progress bar it gets cut off. See the picture attached. The code I have now is:

CSS:

```
.mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail .mejs-time-handle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(../img/sprite.png) 0 -394px;
}
```

HTML (Just a picture because I believe that this is a CSS issue):

[image: HTML]

and this is what it looks like on my page:

[image: Time handle error]

Does anyone know what the issues might be? I feel like I am close to solving it, but I could use some help getting there! Thanks.

Comment: make fiddle of your problem

Comment: i'm using a a jquery plugin. There is too much code involved for fiddle.

Comment: hmm so take a wild chance and add padding-top to the element ... or provide link of your page if it is possible

Comment: it is an in-house project, so I can not provide a link. Although, I did try your suggestion to add padding-top to it. It didn't move the image at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`padding-up` the `div` in which your progress bar is placed will work.

in the class `mejs-time-rail` , add the following code: `padding-top: 5px;` in that class. if that doesn't work, try to increase the `5px` to `10px`

Comment: Could you elaborate? Code example, maybe?

Comment: in the class `mejs-time-rail` , add the following code:

`padding-top: 5px;` in that class. if that doesn't work, try to increase the 5px to 10px

Comment: I'll select this as the answer, but the issue was a min-width option in the CSS of the body.

Comment: Could you elaborate the `min-width` thing ?